# Arangodb remove action error

Tags: arangodb

I want to do some remove action in arangodb transaction. This is my code:

```
  db._executeTransaction
  ({ 
    collections: 
    {
            write: [ "demo" ]
        },
    action: function(){db.demo.removeByExample( {"Hello":"World"} );}
    });
```

And It's always raise some exception. Error Information is:

```
 ERROR JavaScript exception in file 'f:/work_lc/aran
 odb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/arango-database.j
 651: nested transactions detected]
 ERROR !  return TRANSACTION(data);
 ERROR !         ^
```

can somebody help me, Thanks!

Comment: Which version of arangodb do you use?

Comment: Did the answer work for you? if yes, can you mark it 'accepted'? If not, whats missing?

Answer (score 3):

Within a transaction-function `db` is not available, you have to require it with `require("internal").db`

Your code should look like this:

```
  db._executeTransaction
  ({ 
    collections: 
    {
            write: [ "demo" ]
        },
    action: function(){require("internal").db.demo.removeByExample( {"Hello":"World"} );}
    });
```